# "Error: Could not find or load main class Salary" when I try running my saved and compiled java program

Tags: java, macos, terminal

I am using a Mac osx 10.10.5 Yosemite, and I am trying to run my short Java program using Terminal. I first entered: "emacs Salary.java". Then: "javac /Users/username/Documents/Salary.java". And finally: "java Salary". It created a .class file for my java program, yet it says "

> Error: Could not find or load main class Salary"

after I try running it. Am I doing something wrong? I checked the directories and it's in the correct place. The code is provided below, thank you in advance:

```
    public class Salary {

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        int hourlyWage = 20;

        System.out.print("Annual salary is: ");
        System.out.println(hourlyWage * 40 * 50);

        System.out.print("Monthly salary is: ");
        System.out.print((hourlyWage * 40 * 50) / 12);

        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: `java -cp . Salary` (assuming `Salary.class` is in your current working directory)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

Comment: Sorry I over analyzed my problem, I forgot to do cd Documents before all of the steps I provided, it works now.